# Using Selenium to parse a page for links that do not exist in the source

Tags: javascript, python, html, parsing, selenium

I am looking to find a way to code a script in python that can extract the link to each item in my Steam inventory. For those who do not know what that is here is an example:

http://steamcommunity.com/id/timetoidle5/inventory/#753_0

What it should do is be able to extract the `href` link from the blue highlighted field in the image below:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/zTMGJ.png

So it should be able to access each `"item holder"` class and find the value attached to the attribute `href`. After that it should be able to extract the text on the right side of the screen. So in the image example above, it should be able to see the "View applicable games" button, see the text "Tags: Tradable, Not Marketable", etc.

I have done some research and I know how to grab the source from the page or get links based on what attribute it has etc... However, the issue is that the links I want to extract are not even in the source. I'm guessing that it doesn't work because the source changes based on which item you click in the inventory...?

Comment: Generally questions on Stack Overflow are meant to solve problems people have had with implementation.  I think this question is a little too broad.  I would recommend you attempt a solution, then come back and ask questions about specific issues you're having.

Comment: For those who are interested, someone mentioned Phantomjs and Splinter but then their post got deleted (not sure why). I will give those a go.